# How to find which line is missing in another file

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

on Linux box 
I have one file as below 
**A.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
```

Second file as below
**B.txt**

```
1
2
3
6
```

I want to know what is inside A.txt but not in  B.txt
i.e. it should print value  4

I want to do that on Linux.

Comment: Not sure why this was considered "unclear" - `comm` is the command you're looking for. In this specific case `comm -23 A.txt B.txt`.

Comment: It seems that "unclear" is being used for lack of a "no effort" closer.

Comment: This is a great question - it described my exact problem in a way that I was able to find on google easily, and it has answers I can use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}!a[$0]' B A
```

didn't test, give it a try

Comment: [Explanation of why it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32488079/213816)

Comment: That would populate `a[]` with the superset of values from both files and so use more memory than necessary. It's better to do `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' B A` instead so it only has to hold the contents of `B` in memory.

Answer (score 21):

Use comm if the files are sorted as your sample input shows:

```
$ comm -23 A.txt B.txt
4
```

If the files are unsorted, see @Kent's awk solution.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the actual answer!

Answer (score 9):

You can also do this using grep by combining the `-v` (show non-matching lines), `-x` (match whole lines) and `-f` (read patterns from file) options:

```
$ grep -v -x -f B.txt A.txt
4
```

This does not depend on the order of the files - it will remove any lines from A that match a line in B.

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm, doesn't even require lines to be sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

(An addition to @rjmunro's answer)

The proper way to use `grep` for this is:

```
$ grep -F -v -x -f B.txt A.txt
4
```

Without the `-F` flag, `grep` interprets PATTERN, read from `B.txt`, as a basic regular expression (BRE), which is undesired here, and can cause troubles. `-F` flag makes `grep` treat PATTERN as a set of newline-separated strings. For instance:

```
$ cat A.txt
&
^
[
]

$ cat B.txt
[
^
]
|

$ grep -v -x -f B.txt A.txt
grep: B.txt:1: Invalid regular expression

$ grep -F -v -x -f B.txt A.txt
&
```

Comment: This is obviously the best answer. It can be written slightly more compact as `grep -Fvx -f B.txt A.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Using diff:

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' A.txt B.txt
```

Comment: I am not sure if `diff` will work on this problem. think about in A, I have from 1-10, but in B I have 9-1 and 100-200. all are unsorted. the output should be 10.

Comment: On the question the files are sorted. It wont work on unsorted files. You can use sort or any other shell command to sort the file.