# Unix-Read File Line by line.Check if a string exists on another file and do required operation

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I need some assistance on the below.

File1.txt

```
aaa:/path/to/aaa:777
bob:/path/to/bbb:700
ccc:/path/to/ccc:600
```

File2.txt

```
aaa:/path/to/aaa:700
bbb:/path/to/bbb:700
ccc:/path/to/ccc:644
```

I should iterate file2.txt and if aaa exists in File1.txt, then i should compare the file permission. If the file permission is same for aaa in both the files then ignore.

If they are different then write them in the output.txt

So in above case

Output.txt

```
aaa:/path/to/aaa:700
ccc:/path/to/ccc:644
```

How can i achieve this in unix shell script? Please suggest

Comment: 1) write code 2) execute code 3) debug code. You are entirely responsible for #1-2, we (maybe) help with #3.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment of @Marc that you should try something before asking here.
However, the following answer is difficult to find when you never have seen the constructions, so I give you something to study.

When you want to parse line by line, you can start with

```
while IFS=: read -r file path mode; do
   comparewith=$(grep "^${file}:${path}:" File2.txt | cut -d: -f3)
   # compare and output
done < File1.txt
```

For large files that will become very slow.
You can first filter the lines you want to compare from File2.txt.
You want to `grep` strings like `aaa:/path/to/aaa:`, including the last `:`. With `cut -d: -f1-2` you might be fine with your inputfile, but maybe it is better to remove the last three characters:
`sed 's/...$//' File1.txt`.
You can let grep use the output as a file with expressions using `<()`:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/...$//' File1.txt) File2.txt
```

Your example files don't show the situation when both files have identical lines (that you want to skip), you will need another process substitution to get that working:

```
grep -v -f File1.txt <(grep -f <(sed 's/...$//' File1.txt ) File2.txt )
```

Another solution, worth trying yourself, is using `awk` (see [What is "NR==FNR" in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-is-nr-fnr-in-awk) for accessing 2 files).

Answer (score 0):

`comm - compare two sorted files line by line`

According to manual, `comm -13 <file1> <file2>` must print only lines unique to `<file2>`:

```
$ ls
File1.txt  File2.txt
$ cat File1.txt 
aaa:/path/to/aaa:777
bbb:/path/to/bbb:700
ccc:/path/to/ccc:600
$ cat File2.txt 
aaa:/path/to/aaa:700
bbb:/path/to/bbb:700
ccc:/path/to/ccc:644
$ comm -13 File1.txt File2.txt 
aaa:/path/to/aaa:700
ccc:/path/to/ccc:644
$ # Nice!
```

But it doesn't check for lines in `<file1>` that are "similar" to corresponding lines of `<file2>`. I. e. it won't work as you want if `File1.txt` has line `BOB:/path/to/BOB:700` and `File2.txt` has `BBB:/path/to/BBB:700` since it will print the latter (while you want it not to be printed).

It also won't do what you want if strings `bbb:/path/to/bbb:700` and `bbb:/another/path/to/bbb:700` are supposed to be "identical".