# not equal to operator with awk

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

I am not sure what wrong I am doing but I am certainly making some mistake with my awk command.

I have two files, fileA contains names

FileA

```
Abhi
Roma
GiGi
KaKa
```

FileB contains other data with names

```
Abhi 23  Pk
DaDa 43  Gk
Roma 33  Kk
PkPk 22  Aa
```

Now, I trying to print the details of all the names that are absent in fileA.

```
for i in `cat FileA` ; do cat FileB | awk '{ if ($1!='$i') print $0_}'>> Result; done
```

What I get is

```
Abhi    23  Pk
DaDa    43  Gk
Roma    33  Kk
PkPk    22  Aa
Abhi    23  Pk
DaDa    43  Gk
Roma    33  Kk
PkPk    22  Aa
Abhi    23  Pk
DaDa    43  Gk
```

Desired output

```
DaDa 43  Gk
PkPk 22  Aa
```

Could anyone help me in finding out the error.

Thank you

Comment: Update your question, if necessary, after updating your code to `while IFS= read -r i; do awk -v i="$i" '$1 != i {print $0}' FileB; done < FileA > Result`. (See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).)

Comment: Note to people like me: when you have `!=` in awk expression, use single quotes`' != '` instead of double quotes `" != "`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this you just need `grep`:

```
$ grep -vf fileA fileB
DaDa 43  Gk
PkPk 22  Aa
```

This uses `fileA` to obtain the patterns from. Then, `-v` inverts the match.

[AwkMan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413515/1983854) addresses very well why you are not matching lines properly. Now, let's see where your solution needs polishing:

Your code is:

```
for i in `cat FileA`
do
    cat FileB | awk '{ if ($1!='$i') print $0_}'>> Result
done
```

[Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) explains it well. So you would need to say something like the described in [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/1983854):

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    cat FileB | awk '{ if ($1!='$i') print $0_}'>> Result
done < fileA
```

Then, you are saying `cat file | awk '...'`. For this, `awk '...' file` is enough:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    awk '{ if ($1!='$i') print $0_}' FileB >> Result
done < fileA
```

Also, the redirection could be done at the end of the `done`, so you have a clearer command:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    awk '{ if ($1!='$i') print $0_}' FileB
done < fileA >> Result
```

Calling `awk` so many times is not useful and you can use the [`FNR==NR` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/1983854) to process two files together.

Let's now enter in `awk`. Here you want to use some kind of variable to compare results. However, `$i` is nothing to `awk`.

Also, when you have a sentence like:

```
awk '{if (condition) print $0}' file
```

It is the same to say:

```
awk 'condition' file
```

Because `{print $0}` is the default action to perform when a condition evaluates to true.

Also, to let `awk` use a bash variable you need to use `awk -v var="$shell_var"` and then use `var` internally-

All together, you should say something like:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    awk -v var="$line" '$1 != var' FileB
done < fileA >> Result
```

But since you are looping through the file many times, it will print the lines many, many times. That's why you have to go all the way up to this answer and use `grep -vf fileA fileB`.

Comment: @Angelo see a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you want to compare with a string, that string must be between quotes, otherwise, it assumes that the string is a variable name.

For example:

```
awk '{ if ($1!=name) print $0_}'
```

In this case, awk will assume that "name" is a variable, which will be empty, as no value has been assigned to it, and hence, compare $1 with an empty string.

```
awk '{ if ($1!="name") print $0_}'
```

In this case, awk will compare $1 with the string "name".

Therefore, the correct code for you is:

```
for i in `cat FileA` ; do cat FileB | awk -v var="$i" '{ if ($1!=var) print $0_}'>> Result; done
```

This will also work, though I think it is clearer in the previous way:

```
for i in `cat FileA` ; do cat FileB | awk '{ if ($1!="'$i'") print $0_}'>> Result; done
```

EDIT: Check [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413461/6099313) answer for a better approach in the solution

Comment: no, for i in `cat file` is not a good advise. Neither looping through the files this way. See my answer.

Comment: I agree it is not a good advise, but he wanted to know what was the problem in awk. I just limited to answer that issue.

Comment: Yes, I agree on that and +1 for a good explanation on it. However, indicating a better approach would make your answer shine even more :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll mention you in my answer, as you have already explained a better approach

Answer (score 1):

this task looks like classical [Two-file processing](https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) pattern:

```
# prints lines that are not both in fileA & fileB (inv intersection)
$ awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a) ' fileA fileB
```

so here:

- `NR==FNR` is True only when reading 1st file
- `a[$1]` - create element with 1st column from fileA as key
  a[$0] is same in this example, as $0==$1
  one could write `++a[$1]` to count duplicates if needed same time.
  or `a[$1]=$2` to store some extra info
- `next` - stops further processing, while reading 1st file, e.g. FileA
- `!($1 in a)` - this part will start being executed while reading FileB
  and it will print only lines from it when a[$1] exists,
  e.g. there is element with key equal to $1.
  Note, its equivalent to `!($1 in a) {print $0}`,
  so printing format could be modified if desired...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'NR==FNR ? __[$_] : $!_ in __==_' <( printf '%s' "$test1" )
>                                        <( printf '%s' "$test2" )
> ```

```
DaDa 43  Gk
PkPk 22  Aa
```

or make it without the ternary operator :

> ```
> gawk '$!_ in __ != (FNR < NR || __[$_])'
> ```

```
DaDa 43  Gk
PkPk 22  Aa
```