# Vlookup-like function using awk in ksh

Tags: arrays, awk, ksh, vlookup, aix

#### Disclaimers:

1) English is my second language, so please forgive any gramatical horrors you may find. I am pretty confident you will be able to understand what I need despite these.

2) I have found several examples in this site that address questions/problems similar to mine, though I was unfortunately not able to figure out the modifications that would need to be introduced to fit my needs.

3) You will find some text in capital letters here and there. Is is of course not me "shouting" at you, but only a way to make portions of text stand out. Plase do not consider this an act of unpoliteness.

4) For those of you who get to the bottom of this novella alive, THANKS IN ADVANCE for your patience, even if you do not get to be able to/feel like help/ing me. My disclamer here would be the fact that, after surfing the site for a while, I noticed that the most common "complaint" from people willing to help seems to be lack of information (and/or the lack of quality) provided by the ones seeking for help. I then preferred to be accused of overwording if need be... It would be, at least, not a common offense...

---

#### The "Problem":

I have 2 files (a and b for simplification). File a has 7 columns separated by commas. File b has 2 columns separated by commas.

What I need: Whenever the data in the 7th column of file a matches -EXACT MATCHES ONLY- the data on the 1st column of file b, a new line, containing the whole line of file a plus column 2 of file b is to be appended into a new file "c".

#### --- MORE INFO IN THE NOTES AT THE BOTTOM ---

file a:

```
Server Name,File System,Path,File,Date,Type,ID
horror,/tmp,foldera/folder/b/folderc,binaryfile.bin,2014-01-21 22:21:59.000000,typet,aaaaaaaa
host1,/,somefolder,test1.txt,2016-08-18 00:00:20.000000,typez,11111111
host20,/,somefolder/somesubfolder,usr.cfg,2015-12-288 05:00:20.000000,typen,22222222
hoster,/lol,foolie,anotherfile.sad,2014-01-21 22:21:59.000000,typelol,66666666
hostie,/,someotherfolder,somefile.txt,2016-06-17 18:43:12.000000,typea,33333333
hostile,/sad,folder22,higefile.hug,2016-06-17 18:43:12.000000,typeasd,77777777
hostin,/var,folder30,someotherfile.cfg,2014-01-21 22:21:59.000000,typo,44444444
hostn,/usr,foldie,tinyfile.lol,2016-08-18 00:00:20.000000,typewhatever,55555555
server10,/usr,foldern,tempfile.tmp,2016-06-17 18:43:12.000000,tipesad,99999999
```

file b:

```
ID,Size
11111111,215915
22222222,1716
33333333,212856
44444444,1729
55555555,215927
66666666,1728
88888888,1729
99999999,213876
bbbbbbbb,26669080
```

Expected file c:

```
Server Name,File System,Path,File,Date,Type,ID,Size
host1,/,somefolder,test1.txt,2016-08-18 00:00:20.000000,typez,11111111,215915
host20,/,somefolder/somesubfolder,usr.cfg,2015-12-288 05:00:20.000000,typen,22222222,1716
hoster,/lol,foolie,anotherfile.sad,2014-01-21 22:21:59.000000,typelol,66666666,1728
hostie,/,someotherfolder,somefile.txt,2016-06-17 18:43:12.000000,typea,33333333,212856
hostin,/var,folder30,someotherfile.cfg,2014-01-21 22:21:59.000000,typo,44444444,1729
hostn,/usr,foldie,tinyfile.lol,2016-08-18 00:00:20.000000,typewhatever,55555555,215927
server10,/usr,foldern,tempfile.tmp,2016-06-17 18:43:12.000000,tipesad,99999999,213876
```

#### Additional notes:

0) Notice how line with ID "aaaaaaaa" in file a does not make it into file c since ID "aaaaaaaa" is not present in file b. Likewise, line with ID "bbbbbbbb" in file b does not make it into file c since ID "bbbbbbbb" is not present in file a and it is therefore never looked out for in the first place.

1) Data is clearly completely made out due to confidenciality issues, though the examples provided fairly resemble what the real files look like.

2) I added headers just to provide a better idea of the nature of the data. The real files don't have it, so no need to skip them on the source file nor create it in the destination file.

3) Both files come sorted by default, meaning that IDs will be properly sorted in file b, while they will be most likely scrambled in file a. File c should preferably follow the order of file a (though I can manipulate later to fit my needs anyway, so no worries there, as long as the code does what I need and doesn't mess up with the data by combining the wrong lines).

#### 4) VERY VERY VERY IMPORTANT:

4.a) I already have a "working" ksh code (attached below) that uses "cat", "grep", "while" and "if" to do the job. It worked like a charm (well, acceptably) with 160K-lines sample files (it was able to output 60K lines -approx- an hour, which, in projection, would yield an acceptable "20 days" to produce 30 million lines [KEEP ON READING]), but somehow (I have plenty of processor and memory capacity) cat and/or grep seem to be struggling to process a real life 5Million-lines file (both file a and b can have up to 30 million lines each, so that's the maximum probable amount of lines in the resulting file, even assuming 100% lines in file a find it's match in file b) and the c file is now only being feed with a couple hundred lines every 24 hours.

4.b) I was told that awk, being stronger, should succeed where the more weaker commands I worked with seem to fail. I was also told that working with arrays might be the solution to my performance problem, since all data is uploded to memory at once and worked from there, instead of having to cat | grep file b as many times as there are lines in file a, as I am currently doing.

4.c) I am working on AIX, so I only have sh and ksh, no bash, therefore I cannot use the array tools provided by the latter, that's why I thought of AWK, that and the fact that I think AWK is probably "stronger", though I might be (probably?) wrong.

Now, I present to you the magnificent piece of ksh code (obvious sarcasm here, though I like the idea of you picturing for a brief moment in your mind the image of the monkey holding up and showing all other jungle-crawlers their future lion king) I have managed to develop (feel free to laugh as hard as you need while reading this code, I will not be able to hear you anyway, so no feelings harmed :P ):

```
cat "${file_a}" | while read -r line_file_a; do

    server_name_file_a=`echo "${line_file_a}" | awk -F"," '{print $1}'`
    filespace_name_file_a=`echo "${line_file_a}" | awk -F"," '{print $2}'`
    folder_name_file_a=`echo "${line_file_a}" | awk -F"," '{print $3}'`
    file_name_file_a=`echo "${line_file_a}" | awk -F"," '{print $4}'`
    file_date_file_a=`echo "${line_file_a}" | awk -F"," '{print $5}'`
    file_type_file_a=`echo "${line_file_a}" | awk -F"," '{print $6}'`
    file_id_file_a=`echo "${line_file_a}" | awk -F"," '{print $7}'`

    cat "${file_b}" | grep ${object_id_file_a} | while read -r line_file_b; do

        file_id_file_b=`echo "${line_file_b}" | awk -F"," '{print $1}'`
        file_size_file_b=`echo "${line_file_b}" | awk -F"," '{print $2}'`

        if [ "${file_id_file_a}" = "${file_id_file_b}" ]; then

            echo "${server_name_file_a},${filespace_name_file_a},${folder_name_file_a},${file_name_file_a},${file_date_file_a},${file_type_file_a},${file_id_file_a},${file_size_file_b}" >> ${file_c}.csv

        fi

    done

done
```

#### One last additional note, just in case you wonder:

The "if" section was not only built as a mean to articulate the output line, but it servers a double purpose, while safe-proofing any false positives that may derive from grep, IE 100 matching 1000 (Bear in mind that, as I mentioned earlier, I am working on AIX, so my grep does not have the -m switch the GNU one has, and I need matches to be exact/absolute).

#### You have reached the end. CONGRATULATIONS! You've been awarded the medal to patience.

Comment: I appreciate the effort that went into this Q, and I hope that taking the time to write it up helped you clarify you thinking, but after 3 hrs and no one has replied to your Q (well maybe later, it is the weekend), your Q is likely too complex. You should now spend your time turning this into a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/mcve). Also, your problem sounds sort of like a `join` utility problem. Maybe if you pre-process your data to have the 2nd line folded into the first line in a tmp copy, you can then use `join` to create your output and post process.

Comment: And if you can spare the time, work thru the awk "tutorial" at http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . The process you have designed will work, but it is very inefficient and can likely be replaced with 1 awk program, (may in a pipleline with a few other things) (and if `join` doesn't answer your problem). Good luck.

Comment: Is the first field of file 'b' unique, or might multiple occurrences of the same value be found? Also, how much physical memory is in the system(s) that will run this, and are you able to affect per-process limits in case an in-memory array containing all of file "b" exceeds your default limits?

Comment: Shellter, I will certainly have your comments in mind for future participations. And based on how AWK solved my problem you can bet I will dive deeper into it, since I am currently using it solely as a "tool to work with colums" and to do some math eventually. It is clearly a powerfull beast once you get to tame it.

Comment: Gothi, I deem this question answered by now (see my reply to Jas for further info), anyway, the first field in file b is unique, yes and the affected system has 20GB of physical memory. As for the limits I could not say for sure since I cannot access as the root user, though I'd adventure to say those are unlimited or at it's maximum possible value. IMO, the performance problem I was experiencing was not rooted on the size of the source files nor the amount of lines/records they had, but rather in the inefficiency of my code, calling cat & grep processes literally millions of times.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat stuff.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next }
$7 in a { print $0, a[$7] }
```

Note the order for providing the files to the awk command, `b` first, followed by `a`:

```
$ awk -f stuff.awk b.txt a.txt
host1,/,somefolder,test1.txt,2016-08-18 00:00:20.000000,typez,11111111,215915
host20,/,somefolder/somesubfolder,usr.cfg,2015-12-288 05:00:20.000000,typen,22222222,1716
hoster,/lol,foolie,anotherfile.sad,2014-01-21 22:21:59.000000,typelol,66666666,1728
hostie,/,someotherfolder,somefile.txt,2016-06-17 18:43:12.000000,typea,33333333,212856
hostin,/var,folder30,someotherfile.cfg,2014-01-21 22:21:59.000000,typo,44444444,1729
hostn,/usr,foldie,tinyfile.lol,2016-08-18 00:00:20.000000,typewhatever,55555555,215927
server10,/usr,foldern,tempfile.tmp,2016-06-17 18:43:12.000000,tipesad,99999999,213876
```

Comment: Jas, you have no idea to what extent you have made my life easier. Your little monster ate 5 million lines in like 4 hours. I am speechless. From the bottom of my heart I salute you and your happy dancing bear!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @StuffCompiler, The bear and I couldn't be more pleased that it was useful to you!

Comment: @StuffCompiler If this solved your problem you should accept jas' answer :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Updated calculation
You can try to predict how often you are calling another program:
At least 7 awk's + 1 cat + 1 grep for each line in file a multiplied by 2 awk's for each line in file b. 
(9 * 160.000).
For file b: 2 awk's, one file open and one file close for each hit. With 60K output, that would be 4 * 60.000.

A small change in the code can change this into "only" 160.000 times a grep:

```
cat "${file_a}" | while IFS=, read -r server_name_file_a \
   filespace_name_file_a folder_name_file_a file_name_file_a \
   file_date_file_a file_type_file_a file_id_file_a; do
   grep "${object_id_file_a}" "${file_b}" | while IFS="," read -r line_file_b; do
        if [ "${file_id_file_a}" = "${file_id_file_b}" ]; then
            echo "${server_name_file_a},${filespace_name_file_a},${folder_name_file_a},${file_name_file_a},${file_date_file_a},${file_type_file_a},${file_id_file_a},${file_size_file_b}" 
        fi
    done
done >> ${file_c}.csv
```

Well, try this with your 160K files and see how much faster it is.
Before I explain that this still is the wrong way I will make another small improvement: I will move the `cat` for the while loop to the end (after `done`).

```
while IFS=, read -r server_name_file_a \
   filespace_name_file_a folder_name_file_a file_name_file_a \
   file_date_file_a file_type_file_a file_id_file_a; do
   grep "${object_id_file_a}" "${file_b}" | while IFS="," read -r line_file_b; do
        if [ "${file_id_file_a}" = "${file_id_file_b}" ]; then
            echo "${server_name_file_a},${filespace_name_file_a},${folder_name_file_a},${file_name_file_a},${file_date_file_a},${file_type_file_a},${file_id_file_a},${file_size_file_b}" 
        fi
    done
done < "${file_a}" >> ${file_c}.csv
```

The main drawback of the solutions is that you are reading the complete file_b again and again with your grep for each line in file a.

This solution is a nice improvement in the performance, but still a lot overhead with `grep`. Another huge improvement can be found with `awk`.
The best solution is using awk as explained in [What is "NR==FNR" in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/3220113) and found in the answer of @jas.
It is only one system call and both files are only read once.

Comment: Walter A, Jas code worked like a charm. Either way, I sincerely thank you for taking the time to read my question and propose improvements to my inefficient code. This is my first participation in this site and it has certainly made me ragain a little hope on humanity.