# How to combine a echo/print command with another command such as cat or sed

Tags: linux, unix, aix

I have come across a scenario where I need to print text part of the same line when using the cat command or sed command for example.

I have a file with 5 line in it showing

```
Tom

Seniorsupport

5

U
```

My aim is to print specific text in front of each line giving it another column being more specific

OUTPUT I WANT:

```
Grantee/Username:   Tom

Role name:          Seniorsupport

Priority:           5

Usertype:           U
```

There are many ways this can be done, but I would like a quick and easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I have decided to go about this is using the awk command.

```
cat filename | awk '{print "Grantee/Username:   " $1}' | sed -n '1p'
```

The above command will cat the file and print the text using the awk function printing only line 1 within the file using the sed command

Comment: To print specfic text for each line modify the sed command number to two for example to print text for line 2 (sed -n '2p')

Comment: Please post your code by editing the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the titles (column 1 ) stay in file1 and the actual values in file2 and then you can paste them side by side using `paste` command like this:

```
$ cat file1
Grantee/Username
Role name
Priority
Usertype
$ cat file2
Tom
Seniorsupport
5
U
$ paste <(awk '{printf "%-19s\n", $0 ":"}' file1) file2
Grantee/Username:   Tom
Role name:          Seniorsupport
Priority:           5
Usertype:           U
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the headers in another file ("keyfile").
Combine data and keys with awk. Using the tricks explained in [What is "NR==FNR" in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/3220113) you can write

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0; next} {printf("%-20s%s\n", a[FNR] ":", $0) }' keyfile datafile
```