# How to match one filename to another filename in Linux?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a List.txt with the list of thousand of folders and files of them which looks similar to this

```
cat List.txt

folder1, filestar
folder2, filefish
folder3, filedoll
folder4, filegoose
```

and this goes on. And I have filenames in separated directories (names of directories: sample1, sample2, sample3 …) which match the filenames on a List.txt. So the question is how to find the matching filenames with the files of folders in a list?
And I found the command which lists only files inside of directories.

```
ls -lA sample* | awk -F':[0-9]* ' '/:/{print $2}' | awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }'
```

I just don't know how to print only the files which match with the filenames of List.txt

Comment: So you have files like `sample1/folder1/filestar`? What is the output you're trying to get?

Comment: No, I have  sample1/filestar sample2/filegoose sample3/filedoll  and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=1;next}$NF in a' List.txt FS=/ <(find)
```

Comment: woow, its working!! Thank you! And I have one more question, what if in that list there are folder, filename, creation time, modification time, ownerofthefile, looks similar to this

Comment: `folder1, filestar, 1990/12/12, 1999/10/09 10:35, john`
`folder2, filefish, 1989/10/19, 1989/12/12 11:54, Henrik.`
`folder3, filedoll, 2000/07/03, 2005/04/09 10:12, jenny`
`folder4, filegoose, 1994/09/10, 1997/11/11 10:20, sarah`

Comment: @Asel By default, awk splits records by transitions from whitespace to non-whitespace. If that's suitable for your file format, you just count. In your example the file name is the second field, so `$2`.

Comment: So my task is to find matching file and if they match, to change the modification time to that which is inside of List.txt... I found how to change the timestamp of the file of another file with the command `touch -t ` but I don't know how to combine the code which you wrote and touch command.. Is there a way to do that?? Thank you

Comment: @Asel That's a complete different question. You should try and ask another question when you got stuck. Please tick the green check mark if this answer helped you with the (orignial) question.

Comment: @Asel One last thing: If you want to deal with `, ` (comma plus space) as field separator, you could `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=1;next}$NF in a' FS=', ' file FS=/ <(find)`.

Comment: oh okey, got it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to research about the command you provided me, but couldn't find proper answer. Can you please briefly explain me this part please? `NR==FNR{a[$2]=1;next}$NF`  Thank you @steffen!!

Comment: @Asel Sure! `NR==FNR`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/845034; `a[$2]=1` builds an index on field 2, so we can check if something is indexed later with `... in a`. Then `$NR` is the last field (`$1` is the first element, $2 the second, `NF` contains the number of fields, so `$NF` is the last field). For the second input, we've changed the field separator to `/`, so the last field would be the filename.