# I want to transfer file one specific value into single coat of another file using script

Tags: shell

There is file1 and file2.
In file 1 there is a information `firstname=abc` and in second file there is `firstname=''`.
So the value from firstname file 'abc' have to get in single coat of another files firstname using script.

Comment: File1 -> Firstname=abc
File2 -> Firstname=' ' 

Expected output

File2 -> 'abc'

Comment: You can try something like `https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/3220113` using `=` as delimiter.