# How to compare 2 files and print out only selected info?

Tags: linux, bash, sudoers, passwd

I am trying to compare these 2 files and only print out what I need as the desire output.

```
File1: 
012345:x:9012345:9012345:John Smith:/home/bin/bash
543210:x:9876543:9876543:Troy Denver:/home/bin/bash
111111:x:9898989:9898989:Mathew Moore:/home/bin/bash
222222:x:0101010:0101010:Chuck Maxwell:/homebin/bash
333333:x:1212121:1212121:Bob Evans:/home/bin/bash

File2:
333333 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
543210 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
222222 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Desired Output: 
333333 Bob Evans
543210 Troy Denver
222222 Chuck Maxwell
```

this is what I've done

```
readarray num1 < file1 | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $1}'
while read -r $num1;
        do grep "$num1" file2
        echo "$num1" | awk -F':' '{print $1,$5}'

done < file3.txt
```

Comment: It is hard to tell you where your problem(s) are because you did not show your code. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: my bad, this is my first post. I just added the piece of code that I've done so far

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/3220113

Comment: Try `while read -r firstfield otherfields; do ... done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU join, sort, sed and bash:

```
join -j 1 -t : <(sort File1) <(sed 's/ /:/' File2 | sort) -o 1.1,1.5 | sed 's/:/ /'
```

Output:

```
222222 Chuck Maxwell
333333 Bob Evans
543210 Troy Denver
```

---

See: `man join`