# Compare two columns of one file to two columns in another file

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files as shown below.

First file:

```
Start State,Next State,Session Count,Transition%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,1126,28.600%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/LA_product_view,818,20.780%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/orders/price,21,0.530%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/login/,997,25.330%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/organizations,31,0.780%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/partsVisualizer,167,4.240%
```

Second file:

```
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/LA_product_view,894,13.100%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,1184,17.350%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/orders/price,25,0.360%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/searchresults,226,3.310%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/inventories/LA_entry,3,0.040%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/cart,51,0.740%
```

I need to compare the first two columns of the first file and the first two columns of the second file and if they both match it should print 3,4 columns of both file. If both the files has unique they should be listed with NA from the both files.

My output should be like:

```
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/LA_product_view,818,20.780%,894,13.100%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,1126,28.600%,1184,17.350%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/orders/price,21,0.530%,25,0.360%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/searchresults,NA,NA,226,3.310%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/inventories/LA_entry,NA,NA,3,0.040%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/cart,NA,NA,51,0.740%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/organizations,31,0.780%,NA,NA
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/partsVisualizer,167,4.240%,NA,NA
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/login/,997,25.330%,NA,NA
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-is-nr-fnr-in-awk

Comment: can u help me with an example..!

Comment: Search in stackoverflow for `awk nr==fnr`.

Comment: There are probably 100+ examples on SO alone for joining two files on multiple columns with awk.

Comment: But i could'nt find one as my similar case ...sorry for that could you please help me if you can

Comment: Do your files look so messy, or is it just the editing which failed?

Answer (score 0):

awk -f rag.awk file1 file2 where rag.awk is:

```
    BEGIN {
FS=OFS=","
}
{idx=$1 OFS $2; _34=$3 OFS $4}
FNR==NR {if (FNR>1) f1[idx]=_34; next}
idx in f1 { print idx, f1[idx], _34; delete f1[idx];next}
{print idx, "NA","NA", _34}
END {
  for (i in f1)
     print i, f1[i], "NA", "NA"
}
```

output:

```
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/LA_product_view,818,20.780%,894,13.100%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,1126,28.600%,1184,17.350%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/orders/price,21,0.530%,25,0.360%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/searchresults,NA,NA,226,3.310%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/inventories/LA_entry,NA,NA,3,0.040%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/cart,NA,NA,51,0.740%
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/organizations,31,0.780%,NA,NA
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/partsVisualizer,167,4.240%,NA,NA
/ccstoreui/v1/pages/layout/home,/ccstoreui/v1/login/,997,25.330%,NA,NA
```