# Loop to read from the file and write it to another file using shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have an xml file which contains below

```
<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName>
<jobs>
<job>
```

I want output like below

```
<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original MC This is New Deep</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal MC This is New Deep</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original MC This is Mayurika</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal MC This is Mayurika</eName>
<jobs>
<job>
```

CODE

```
#!/bin/bash
while read whole_line ;
do
name=`echo "$whole_line" | awk '{$1=""; print}'`
LO="<eName>Licensed Original MC ${name}</eName>"
awk -v diff="$LO" '{ if(NR==2) { print diff}
                              else {print $0} } ' southBalanceRecon.xml >>LO.xml

LR="<eName>Licensed Reversal MC ${name}</eName>"
awk -v diff="$LR" '{ if(NR==14) { print diff}
                              else {print $0} } ' LO.xml >> LR.xml
done < file.txt
```

FILE.txt

```
C71 This is New Deep
C72 This is Mayurika
```

When i am trying to run my code i am not getting the probable output which i mentioned above.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `awk` inside a loop. Let `awk` do the looping.

Look at [What is "NR==FNR" in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/3220113) for understanding the `NR==FNR` part.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[NR]=$0; next }
     {
        $1=""
        for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++)  {
           if (i==2)
              print "<eName>Licensed Original MC" $0 "</eName>";
           else if (i==7)
              print "<eName>Licensed Reversal MC" $0 "</eName>";
           else
              print a[i];
        }
     }' southBalanceRecon.xml file.txt
```