# diff unix how to show line number of the source file into the output

Tags: unix, diff

I use diff to show differences in two files.

I want to show Line number in the result of the source into the output.

Example :

File A.csv

1 Test

2 Essai

3 Same

File B.csv

1 Appli

2 Essai

3 Another

**Diff result**

diff A.csv B.csv

1 Test | Appli

3 Same | Another

Comment: Your sample input and expected output is not clear, please do EDIT your post and wrap samples in CODE TAGS.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where you could use the technique of [What is "NR==FNR" in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/3220113)
Another solution might be

```
paste -d"|" A.csv B.csv | nl |  grep -Ev '^(\s*[0-9]*\s*)(.*)\|\2$'
```