# grep reverse with exact matching

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I have a list file, which has id and number and am trying to get those lines from a master file which do not have those ids.

List file

```
nw_66 17296
nw_67 21414
nw_68 21372
nw_69 27387
nw_70 15830
nw_71 32348
nw_72 21925
nw_73 20363
```

master file

```
nw_1 5896
nw_2 52814
nw_3 14537
nw_4 87323
nw_5 56466
......
......
nw_n xxxxx
```

so far am trying this but not working as expected.

```
for i in $(awk '{print $1}' list.txt); do grep -v -w $i master.txt; done;
```

Kindly help

Comment: Could you please post expected output in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {id[$1]=1;next}
{
    if (id[$1] == "") {
        print $0
    }
}' listfile masterfile
```

We accept 2 files as input above, first one is `listfile`, second is `masterfile`.

[`NR == FNR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-imply) would be true while `awk` is going through `listfile`. In the associative array `id[]`, all ids in `listfile` are made a key with value as `1`.

When `awk` goes through `masterfile`, it only prints a line if `$1` i.e. the id is not a key in array `ids`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next}!a[$1]' list master
```

Answer (score 0):

> The OP attempted the following line:
>
> ```
> for i in $(awk '{print $1}' list.txt); do grep -v -w $i master.txt; done;
> ```

This line will not work as for every entry `$i`, you print all entries in `master.txt` tat are not equivalent to `"$i"`. As a consequence, you will end up with multiple copies of `master.txt`, each missing a single line.

Example:

```
$ for i in 1 2; do grep -v -w "$i" <(seq 1 3); done
2     \ copy of seq 1 3 without entry 1
3     /
1     \ copy of seq 1 3 without entry 2
3     /
```

Furthermore, the attempt reads the file `master.txt` multiple times. This is very inefficient.

The unix tool `grep` allows one the check multiple expressions stored in a file in a single go. This is done using the `-f` flag. Normally this looks like:

```
$ grep -f list.txt master.txt
```

The OP can use this now in the following way:

```
$ grep -vwf <(awk '{print $1}' list.txt) master.txt
```

But this would do matches over the full line.

The awk [solution presented by Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646974/8344060) is more flexible and allows the OP to define a more tuned match:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next}!a[$1]' list master
```

Here the OP clearly states, I want to match column 1 of list with column 1 of master and I don't care about spaces or whatever is in column 2. The grep solution could still match entries in column 2.