# awk create a list for testing elements

Tags: awk

I have a list of discrete elements that I want to test inclusion of an entry from each line of my file.  I'd like a succinct way to create a list or array in awk and then test each line against that list.

My list of discrete elements:

ports=(1010, 2020, 3030, 8888, 12345)

**myFile:**

```
127.0.0.1 1010
127.0.0.1 1011
127.0.0.1 12345
127.0.0.1 3333
```

My pseudocode:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    test_ports=[1010, 2020, 3030, 8888, 12345]
  }
  ($2 in test_ports) {
    print $0
  }
' myFile
```

The code below works, but it is not succinct and I don't like how it grows as the list grows, like if I get 100 ports to test against, or 1000...

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    test_ports["1010"]=1
    test_ports["2020"]=1
    test_ports["3030"]=1
    test_ports["8888"]=1
    test_ports["12345"]=1
  }
  ($2 in test_ports) {
    print $0
  }
' myFile
```

Something like this would be good too, but the syntax isn't quite right:

`for i in 1010 2020 3030 8888 12345 {test_ports[i]=1}`

**EDIT**

This code works too and is very close to what I need, but it still seems a bit long for what it's doing.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    ports="1010,2020,3030,8888,12345"
    split(ports, ports_array, ",")
    for (i in ports_array) {test_ports[ports_array[i]] = 1}
  }
  ($2 in test_ports) {
    print $0
  }
' myFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```sh
awk '
  BEGIN {
    ports = "1010 2020 3030 8888 12345"  # ports string
    split(ports, temp)                   # split by space in array temp 
    for (i in temp)                      # populate array test_ports
       test_ports[temp[i]]
  }

  $2 in test_ports                       # print rows with matching ports
' myFile
```

```
127.0.0.1 1010
127.0.0.1 12345
```

A note of explanation:

- `temp` is a numerically indexed array where the ports (1010, 2020, etc) are the array values, indexed from 1
- `test_ports` is an *associative* array where the ports are the array *keys* and the values are null.
- the `elem in array` operator tests if the given element is an *index* (aka "subscript") of the array.

---

**Addendum:** You also have option of reading ports from a file if your ports list is big like this:

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR {ports[$1]; next} $2 in ports' ports.list myfile
```

Or else if you have ports saved in a string then use:

```sh
ports='1010 2020 3030 8888 12345'
awk 'NR==FNR{ports[$1]; next} $2 in ports' <(printf '%s\n' $ports) myfile
```

```
127.0.0.1 1010
127.0.0.1 12345
```

Comment: The advantage of this approach is you can pass the input string using the `-v` option: `awk -v ports="1010 2020 3030 8888 12345" 'BEGIN {split(ports, temp); ...`

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks so much adding nice explanation note

Comment: on the contrary, testing against 100 ports means passing a string of 499 characters, you can see how this scales up. In the end, instead of passing the array hardcoded, you'll have it created dynamically from a string of arbitrary length

Comment: @DaemonPainter: If ports list is so big then it is better to put them in a file and have awk process that file and build array instead of passing a huge string. Awk will have no problems building an array of 500 ports

Comment: I like the separate file approach.  I would usually pass the ports.list file in as a variable and have awk build the ports_array in a BEGIN statement, like `-v ports_file=ports.list 'BEGIN {while ((getline < ports_file) > 0) {test_ports[$0]=1}} ...'`

Comment: As shown in my answer that `awk` has better way to build array from a file instead of `C` style `while ((getline < ports_file) > 0)` loop. But you can do that as well if you like.

Comment: I'm curious to know advantages of the method shown in your answer.  Using while getline keeps the configuration files separate from the input/data files, and it doesn't require testing FNR==NR for every single record, which probably wouldn't matter, but I wonder if it adds up when awk is processing millions or billions of lines of text (some would then argue awk shouldn't be used).

Comment: Using a getline loop to read a dictionary in the BEGIN section isn't the worst idea, you just have to be careful how you implement it (see case "c)" under "Applications" at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) and yes, it would improve performance very, very, slightly but it's usually just not worth writing the extra code. Those who argue that awk shouldn't be used to process billions of lines of text are wrong - awk is typically faster than C for text processing because awk itself is highly optimized for common text processing functionality, unlike equivalent C code people write by hand.

Comment: As one who uses awk to processes billions of lines of code each day, I agree :)  But I get a lot of flak for it, or at least for using bash to wrap functionality around awk.

Comment: Ah, now adding bash around it does open a can of worms - there you can REALLY mess things up :-). If you haven't read it yet, check out Stephane's answer at least at [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for a good discussion of non-obvious issues around text processing in shell and there are plenty of other gotchas!

Answer (score 2):

Since you said `I'd like a succinct way to create a list or array in awk and then test each line against that list`, here is a succinct way to create a list in awk and then test each line against that list:

```
$ awk 'index(",1010,2020,3030,8888,12345,",","$2",")' file
127.0.0.1 1010
127.0.0.1 12345
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -v ports='1010,2020,3030,8888,12345' 'index(","ports",",","$2",")' file
127.0.0.1 1010
127.0.0.1 12345
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand the commas, but I like it!   Nice and succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a large number of ports (test strings) to test against, I'd suggest matching using two files instead of a string.

Let `ports.txt` be the file of ports and `test.txt` your input test file. Be ports.txt something like this:

```
1010
2020
3030
8888
12345
```

then run

```
awk 'NR==FNR{port[$0]=$0} ($2 in a){print}' ports.txt test.txt
```

this will create the `port[]` array from the first file and use it to print if matching in the second file.

This solution expands on the concept proposed in [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64789835/2125110), but with a concise syntax as you were looking for.

More info on the `NR==NFR` syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-imply). A final note on re-usability: attached to an external process, you might have the same awk syntax running against the same `test.txt` file, changing the `ports.txt` file (e.g. `ports1.txt`, `ports2.txt`, `portn.txt` ...) so that you may match port groups instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the ports in `ports.txt`, then you might be able to use join:

```
$ cat ports.txt
1010
2020
3030
8888
12345
$ join -12 -o1.1,2.1 <(sort -bk2 myFile.txt) <(sort -b ports.txt)
127.0.0.1 1010
127.0.0.1 12345
```

Comment: I like outside-the-box solutions!