# Indexing words in a file according to their line with AWK

Tags: awk, indices

Suppose I have a file similar to the following:

```
hello
hello
hi
hi
hello
hey
```

I would like to find the indices of every unique line and using a comma as the indices separator. So ideally, the output would be like:

```
hello 1,2,5
hi 3,4
hey 6
```

What has been done in getting the value of lines by using the following codes,

```
{ arr[$0]++ }
END { for (i in arr) {
        print i
    }
}
```

the result is,

```
hey
hi
hello
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far so we can help you with that. See [ask].

Comment: Please note that the only unique line in your file is "hey".

Comment: if you want a quick look into these, I would use: ```cat -n <file>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this script

```
{
  words[$0] = words[$0] == "" ? FNR : words[$0] "," FNR        # appends the line, sorting for the word
}

END {                                # once we are done reading the file
  for (w in words)                     # for each word, the sorting order depends on awk internal variables.
  {
    print w, words[w]             # prints the desired output
  }
}
```

Please see [Controlling Array Traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html) for more details on how the words are going to be printed out and how to control it. For more details on FNR see [What are NR and FNR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-imply).

Comment: I have tried this script, however, there exist some problems. First, parentheses are needed in the _for_ statement. Second, after fixing it, the result looks like `hey 2`, where the second column of all three lines is 2.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Let me fix that for you. In addition, I took the opportunity to use a more elegant solution to manage the comma on the first line. Still, it is one of the many possibilities. Your implementation was not too far out, but you weren't tracking the line number, only the record content.