# awk match by variable with dot in it

Tags: bash, awk

I have a script that will iterate over a file containing domains (google.com, youtube.com, etc). The purpose of the script is to check how many times each domain is included in the 12th column of a tab seperated value file.

```
while read domain; do
    awk -F '\t' '$12 == '$domain'' data.txt | wc -l
done < domains.txt
```

However awk seems to be interpretating the dots in the domains as a special character. The following error message is shown:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
context is
        $12 ~ >>>  google. <<< com
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

I am a beginner in bash so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesBrown added wc -l. The tsv file has a lot of different outputs. But to clarify the 12th column contains a bunch of domains seperated by commas. An example of values in the 12th column is

autodiscover.intelart.com.br, cpanel.intelart.com.br, equipegoogle.com.br, intelart.com.br, mail.equipegoogle.com.br, mail.intelart.com.br, webdisk.intelart.com.br, webmail.intelart.com.br, www.equipegoogle.com.br, www.intelart.com.br
domains.google.com

Comment: you can't nest single-quotes inside single-quotes. awk is seeing bare expansion of `$domain` not a string or regex

Comment: your code doesn't consider substring matches: if domain is `ab.co` it will match `xab.co`, `ab.com`, etc. If each column 12 is a single domain, just compare with `==`

Comment: @jhnc I have got that covered. The list also contains subdomains (that I want to be counted) so thats why I am not using ==. The focus here is on the dot in variable name. Are you saying I can't use any variables in awk matching?

Comment: If you have fixed the single-quoting mistake in your code, show the new code that demonstrates the problem, not this broken version.

Comment: quoting matters: `awk 'BEGIN{ a=3; print 'a'; print "a"}'` - the first `'a'` is probably not doing what you think it is. consider also: `awk 'BEGIN{ a=3; print '"a"'; print "'a'"}'`

Comment: @jhnc The == or ~ issue is already accounted for. The single-quoting mistake is not. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
domain='google.com'
awk -F '\t' '$12 == '$domain'' data.txt
```

the `$domain` is outside of any quotes:

```
awk -F '\t' '$12 == '$domain'      ' data.txt
            <       >       <      >
            start   end     start  end
```

and so exposed to the shell for interpretation first and THEN it becomes part of the body of the awk script before awk sees it. So what awk sees is:

```
awk -F '\t' '$12 == google.com' data.txt
```

and `google.com` is not a valid symbol (e.g. variable or function) name nor string nor number. What you MEANT to do was:

```
awk -F '\t' '$12 == "'"$domain"'"' data.txt
```

so the shell would see `"$domain"` instead of just `$domain` (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for why that's important) and awk would finally see:

```
awk -F '\t' '$12 == "google.com"' data.txt
```

which is fine as now `"google.com"` is a string, not a symbol BUT you should never allow shell variables to expand to become part of an awk script as there are other caveats so what you should really have done is:

```
awk -F '\t' -v dom="$domain" '$12 == dom' data.txt
```

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for more information.

By the way, even after fixing the above problem do not do this:

```
while read domain; do
    awk -F '\t' -v dom="$domain" '$12 == dom' data.txt | wc -l
done < domains.txt
```

as it'll be immensely slow and contains insidious bugs (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). Do something like this instead (untested):

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR==FNR {
        cnt[$1] = 0
        next
    }
    $12 in cnt {
        cnt[$12]++
    }
    END {
        for ( dom in cnt ) {
            print dom, cnt[dom]
        }
    }
' domains.txt data.txt
```

That will be far more efficient, robust, and portable than calling awk inside a shell read loop.

See [What are NR and FNR and what does "NR==FNR" imply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-imply) for how that awk script works. Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn awk.

Comment: when adding the quotation marks I got awk: non-terminated string google.com... at source line 1 context is <<< $12 ~ >>> "google.com

Comment: Then you copy/pasted incorrectly. Show us the full script that is outputting that error message so we can help you debug it.

Comment: I am also having difficulties understanding your alternative solution. Could you please elaborate on that approach? Again, I am a beginner in bash so I would really appreciate your help

Comment: No point discussing that til we debug your first problem from your comment above but I added a reference that explains it (it's an **extremely** common awk idiom).

Comment: If you'd like help debugging [your current quotation marks problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72786078/awk-match-by-variable-with-dot-in-it#comment128563793_72786501) then show us the script now before we move on to help someone else.

Comment: The script is currently: while read domain; do awk -F '\t' '$12 ~ "'"$domain"'"' data.txt | wc -l done < domains.txt

Comment: That script will only produce the error message you say it does if `$domain`  contains unexpected characters such as `"`s or maybe a backslash at the end. That's one of the reasons not to let a shell variable expand to become part of an awk script - cryptic errors due to input data. As mentioned in my answer - don't do that.

Comment: Why are you using `$12 ~` (a partial regexp match) in the script in your comment when you're using `$12 ==` (a full string match) in your question? It's very unlikely that a partial regexp match would be the best solution for whatever you're trying to do but the fact you think you need it means you may need a partial string instead of full string match which would require a different solution that the one in my answer.

Comment: meant to write ==, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> awk -F '\t' '$12 == '$domain'' data.txt | wc -l
> ```

The single quotes are building an awk program. They are not something visible to awk. So awk sees this:

```
$12 == google.com
```

Since there aren't any quotes around `google.com`, that is a syntax error. You just need to add quotation marks.

```
awk -F '\t' '$12 == "'"$domain"'"'  data.txt
```

The quotes jammed together like that are a little confusing, but it's just this:

```
 '....'    stuff to send to awk. Single quotes are for the shell.
 '..."...' a double quote inside the awk program for awk to see
 '...'"..."  stuff in double quotes _outside_ the awk program for the shell
```

We can combine those like this:

```
 '..."'"$var"'"...'
```

That's a bunch of literal awk code ending in a double-quote, followed by the expansion of the shell parameter var, which is double-quoted as usual in the shell for safety, followed by more literal awk code starting with a double quotes. So the end result is a string passed to awk that includes the value of the var inside double quotes.

But you don't have to be so fancy or confusing since `awk` provides the `-v` option to set variables from the shell:

```
awk -v domain="$domain" '$12 == domain' data.txt
```

Since the `domain` is not quoted inside the awk code, it is interpreted as the name of a variable. (Periods are not legal in variable names, which is why you got a syntax error with your domains; if you hadn't, though, awk would have treated them as empty and been looking for lines whose twelfth field was likewise blank.)

Comment: when adding the quotation marks I got awk: non-terminated string google.com... at source line 1 context is <<<    $12 ~ >>>  "google.com

Comment: First, you should use the `-v` version instead, because it's easier. Second, you must have missed a double-quote. There are four: the open double quote inside the single-quoted awk code, the open outside the single-quotes for the shell, the close still outside single quotes, and the close back inside single quotes for awk.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [`cut`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) to print the 12th column of the TAB-delimited file, [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) and `uniq` to count the items:

```
cut -f12 data.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give the count of how many lines of the input has `"google.com"` in `$12`

```
{m,g}awk -v __="${domain}" '
 BEGIN { _*=\
      (  _ ="\t[^\t]*")*gsub(".",(_)_,_)*sub(".","",_)*\
  gsub("[.:&=/-]","[&]",__)*sub("[[][^[]+$",__"\t?",_)*(\
  
 FS=_ } { _+=NF } END { print _-NR }'
```