# How to paste 2 files in unix

Tags: unix

I have 2 files below are the values and expected output,could anyone please help.

File 1 :

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

FIle 2

```
1
2
3
```

Expected output:

```
1
A
B
C
2
E
F
G
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

The output of this awk script happens to produce the expected output,

**but it's unclear if this is a correct answer to your question**:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[NR]=$0 }NR!=FNR{ if(FNR%3==1) { print a[++i] } print $0 }' file2 file1
```

- `NR==FNR` see: [an explanation of NR and FNR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32482115/724039), the array `a[]` is filled with the values found in file `file2`
- `NR!=FNR` see: [an explanation of NR and FNR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32482115/724039), here file `file1` is read
- `if(FNR%3==1) {...}`  When the value if `FNR%3` equals 1, print the first member of the array `a[]`, and `i` is incremented

This happens to print a line from file2, and then print 3 lines from file1. After this again 1 line from file2, and 3 lines of file1. Then the process stops. Nothing is done with the 3rd line of file2.