# Using grep or other tools for searching a large CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, grep

I have a 4 gig CSV I am trying to search to get a sub set of the CSV. I have a file csv file that contains the keywords I'm searching for (these keywords will be in the first column on the big csv).

I tried this line but it ended up taking over an hour to finish. I needed to use tr to get rid of the windows return char.

```
LC_ALL=C grep -F -i -f <(tr -d '\r' < keywords.csv) big_csv.csv > output.csv
```

Are there anyway I could optimize this? Anything I'm missing? Would it be better to use awk or another tool for this? I even thought about sorting then splitting the big csv by the first row so when when i search I could then just search the keyword by the file name and then append that to a new file. Is there a best practice for this? I'm trying to make this as POSIX as possible

As requested here is some of the sample data.

```
ADLV,-1.741774,0.961072,-0.751392,-0.935572,-2.269994,1.081103,-0.831244,1.540083,0.474326,-1.322924,2.199037,-0.919939,0.641496,-0.584152,0.729028,0.608351,-0.522026,0.966026,-0.793949,-1.623368,1.16177,-0.642438,-0.675811,-0.214964,-2.263053,2.188642,0.302449,0.770106
```

There will be multiple entries of the first row.

There's more data in the rows but it's too long to post here.

the keyword file will be like this

```
ADLV
ADVG
```

At most the keywords.csv will have 1,000 keywords. They will all be 4 letters per keyword.

Here's a gist with sample data https://gist.github.com/fishnibble/9d95658c352a1acab3cec3e965defb3f

Comment: I would give a couple example lines from the "big" csv --  including lines that you want to skip -- And give an example based on that of the file your are trying to create.

Comment: Can you post short samples of input data and intended output? Does the input CSV contain quoted commas?

Comment: [`csvgrep`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvgrep.html) from the csvkit bundle of utilities is nice

Comment: 1. post a small but descriptive sample of the said csv with the related expected output. 2. Use awk.

Comment: please update the question with samples of the two files; for the big file show a couple rows that match and couple rows that do not match; also of interest will be details on `keywords.csv` (number of lines, total MBytes of file); I'm *guessing* the current approach is slow because `keywords.csv` is 'large' as well.

Comment: Sorry for not providing an example. I have updated the post.

Comment: @markp-fuso at most the keywords.csv will be around 1,000

Comment: One line of sample input doesn't give us a [mcve] we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with. Give us, say, 4 or 5 lines with 4 or 5 fields per line of input CSV and the associated expected output from that input.

Comment: @EdMorton I will make a gist with sample data.

Comment: I don't know what that means but if it's something other than a few lines of text that you include as a Code Block in your question then please don't do it. We don't need to see a lot of data to understand your problem so any more than 4 or 5 lines of 4 or 5 fields would just be obscuring what you need to do.

Comment: @EdMorton I have provided sample input with sample data.

Comment: Please don't post images or links in your questions, just text. See [ask].

Comment: @ghoti No, It will not contain any quoted data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any awk, it sounds like all you need is:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{sub(/\r$/,""); keys[$1]; next} $1 in keys' keywords.csv big_csv.csv
```

The `sub(/\r$/,"")` is there because you had `tr -d '\r' < keywords.csv` in your code - if you don't have DOS line endings in your keywords file then you don't need that.

I see you also have `-i` in your grep command, though, which implies you need to make the matching case-insensitive - if so then this is what you need, still using any awk:

```
awk -F, '{key=tolower($1)} NR==FNR{sub(/\r$/,""); keys[key]; next} key in keys' keywords.csv big_csv.csv
```

The `grep` line you tried would not only take a long time to finish but it could also produce incorrect output as it's searching across the whole line of big_csv, not just the first field, and so it would generate a false match if the keyword appeared in some other position in a line, and it would also generate a false match if the keyword you wanted happened to be a substring of some other keyword.

Comment: If we had multiple text on the first columns would this still work? ex AZHA ...data... (new line ) AZHA...diffrent data...

Comment: Multiple people (zak, ghoti, james, me, mark) have all asked you to post a [mcve] in your question (a link to a site containing a whole bunch of input and no expected output is not useful, especially if it doesn't even cover your use cases) so we can help you, Please create and post a [mcve] that covers all of your requirements, including case-insensitivity and whatever the scenario is you just asked about in that comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you'd do it in awk. I'd be interested to see if the duration is longer or shorter.

```
awk -F, '
  NR==FNR { words[$1]; next }
  $1 in words
' keywords.csv big_csv.csv > output.csv
```

It works by reading the first file into an array using the common "first file" test, then checking that array as a key to the second file.

I can update this further if you add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- first field (both files) does not contain commas and is *not* wrapped in double quotes
- data from `keywords.csv` may have windows/dos line endings (`\r`)

Setup:

```
$ cat keywords.csv                         # run through unix2dos to add "\r"
ADLV
ADVG

$ cat big_csv.csv
ADLV,-1.741774,0.961072,-0.751392,-0.935572,-2.269994,1.081103,-0.831244,1.540083,0.474326,-1.322924,2.199037,-0.919939,0.641496,-0.584152,0.729028,0.608351,-0.522026,0.966026,-0.793949,-1.623368,1.16177,-0.642438,-0.675811,-0.214964,-2.263053,2.188642,0.302449,0.770106
WXYZ,-1.741774,0.961072,-0.751392,-0.935572,-2.269994,1.081103,-0.831244,1.540083,0.474326,-1.322924,2.199037,-0.919939,0.641496,-0.584152,0.729028,0.608351,-0.522026,0.966026,-0.793949,-1.623368,1.16177,-0.642438,-0.675811,-0.214964,-2.263053,2.188642,0.302449,0.770106
```

A basic `awk` approach:

```
awk -F, '                                  # input field delimiter is a comma; for 1st file this implies entire line == 1st field
FNR==NR { sub(/\r$/,""); a[$0]; next }     # 1st file: strip off "\r", save line as index in array a[]; skip to next line of input (from 1st file)
$1 in a                                    # 2nd file: if 1st field is an index in array a[] then print current line to stdout
' keywords.csv big_csv.csv > output.csv
```

This generates:

```
$ cat output.csv
ADLV,-1.741774,0.961072,-0.751392,-0.935572,-2.269994,1.081103,-0.831244,1.540083,0.474326,-1.322924,2.199037,-0.919939,0.641496,-0.584152,0.729028,0.608351,-0.522026,0.966026,-0.793949,-1.623368,1.16177,-0.642438,-0.675811,-0.214964,-2.263053,2.188642,0.302449,0.770106
```

Comment: Question on this. If there are multiple ADLV could we still use a hash for this?

Comment: what do you mean by *`multiple ADLV`*? if you mean there could be multiple entries of `ADLV` in `keywords.csv` ... they'll all get hashed into the same/single `a[]` entry; you should update the question with an example of what mean by *`multiple ADLV`*

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: key is in column 1 in both files (`big.csv`, `keys.txt` from your sample data)

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1] = 1; next } a[$1] {print $1,$2}' keys.txt FS=\, big.csv
```

gives:

```
SDGA -1.678247
SDSV -2.140182
WDGV -1.31453
```

(for the sake of readability I just printed the first two columns for matching keys)

I'm not a native speaker (English), so for an explanation of NR, FNR, Arrays and all the stuff going on here, I would like to refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-imply).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice. :) (but you probably don't need to escape the comma in `FS=\,` here)

Comment: You're right! It's just bad habit, cause I usually work with CSVs with ';' as seperator. Then you *have* to mask it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done in Ruby:

```
ruby -e '
# split(/\R/) works the same with DOS or Unix line endings
keys=File.open(ARGV[0]).read.split(/\R/).map(&:downcase).to_set
File.open(ARGV[1]).each_line{|line| 
    tst=line.split(/,/,2)[0].downcase
    puts line if keys.include?(tst)
}
' sample_keyword.csv sample_input.csv >out.csv
```

There is no *particular* advantage to doing the basic example in Ruby. In fact I would do it in awk if the actual use is only what you have described. Ruby is *potentially* faster but often times not.

However, you can do things like output to a different format (JSON, XML, complex csv) that are challenging in awk more easily done in Ruby.

You can replicate `curl` internally in Ruby and read your gist examples directly:

```
ruby -e '
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri1 = URI.parse("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fishnibble/9d95658c352a1acab3cec3e965defb3f/raw/21fc5153a0b78cdb3eab88c72d700cdf74f20ae7/sample_keyword.csv")
keys = Net::HTTP.get(uri1).split(/\R/).map(&:downcase).to_set

# This can be done in a streaming mode for huge data...
uri2 = URI.parse("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fishnibble/9d95658c352a1acab3cec3e965defb3f/raw/21fc5153a0b78cdb3eab88c72d700cdf74f20ae7/sample_input.csv")
Net::HTTP.get(uri2).split(/\R/).each{|line|
    tst=line.split(/,/,2)[0].downcase
    puts line if keys.include?(tst)
}' >out.csv
```

That is where you want Ruby / Python / Perl since that stream is hard to do in awk.  You can also mount external servers or read ftp, etc where that is challenging with awk *alone*.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there anyway I could optimize this? Anything I'm missing?

You commanded GNU `grep` to look for keyword in whole line. This is unnecessary as you want to find lines having said keyword in 1st column, for CSV without quotes in 1st column this would mean line starting with keyword followed by comma (`,`) character.

> Would it be better to use awk or another tool for this?

If you have limited time you should prepare smaller example and then measure various solutions. As `awk` solution were already shown I will propose GNU `sed` solution by reworking your keywords file, say `keywords.txt`

```
ADLV
ADVG
```

into sed file by doing `sed -e 's/^/\/^/' -e 's/[\r\n]*$/,\/p/' keywords.txt > file.sed`

```
/^ADLV,/p
/^ADVG,/p
```

which will create `file.sed` which could be used as follows

```
sed -n -f file.sed file.csv
```

Explanation: `-n` disengage default print action `-f file.sed` execute commands in `file.sed`, in this case these are just `p`rints.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.8)*